# LEFT OUTER JOIN with two conditions doesn't work properly

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

```
SELECT mein.person_id AS per_Id, DATE( mein.timestamp ) AS dates, SUM( nr_pos ) AS pos, SUM( nr_neg ) AS neg, SUM( nr_neu) AS neu, 
op , clo  
FROM base1.q  
LEFT JOIN base1.mein ON DATE( mein.timestamp ) = q.date  
AND mein.person_id = q.id  
WHERE mein.person_id = 1  
GROUP BY q.date, q.id  
ORDER BY mein.person_id, q.date DESC
```

The above code should do the following:
I want to join two tables from my database `base1`, namely `q`and `mein`. This has to happen in a way that they are joined if column `date(mein.timestamp)` and column `q.date`coincide and if column `mein.person_id`and column `q.id`coincide.
The difficulty I have with this is that I want the entries of `q`to be in there even if `date(mein.timestamp)`has no entry, that is why I used the left outer join.
Unfortunately, there are still rows kicked out where `date(mein.timestamp)`has no entry but `q.date`does. How can I manage this to be prevented and leave those rows still in the joint table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
WHERE mein.person_id = 1
```

to

```
WHERE q.id = 1
```

so you get all rows from base1.q where q.id = 1, and, if any rows exist, the corresponding rows from base1.mein which match on mein.timestamp and mein.person_id

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Also thanks to the other proposals. Wow, your asnwers came so fast!!! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

When you test a LEFT JOINed column (`mein.person_id` in your case) in the WHERE clause, you force that join to behave as if it were an INNER JOIN. Instead, make that test part of the join condition.

```
SELECT mein.person_id AS per_Id, DATE( mein.timestamp ) AS dates, SUM( nr_pos ) AS pos, SUM( nr_neg ) AS neg, SUM( nr_neu) AS neu, 
op , clo  
    FROM base1.q  
        LEFT JOIN base1.mein 
            ON DATE( mein.timestamp ) = q.date  
                AND mein.person_id = q.id  
                AND mein.person_id = 1  
    GROUP BY q.date, q.id  
    ORDER BY mein.person_id, q.date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Your join should be

```
LEFT JOIN base1.mein ON DATE( mein.timestamp ) = q.date  
AND mein.person_id = q.id  AND mein.person_id = 1
```